# Assigning to dataframe changes character string to list in R

Tags: r, list, types, dataframe

I'm trying to fill in a dataframe column with character strings pulled from a second dataframe. When I try to do this, however, the new entries in the column turn into lists:

```
for (i in nyc_districts$SUBWAY_STOP){
  nyc_districts$SUBWAY_STOP[i]<-substops$V3[[i]]
}

class(substops$V3[[1]])
[1] "character"

class(nyc_districts$SUBWAY_STOP[1])
[1] "list"
```

What is going on? How can I turn the new entries into strings?
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add reproducible sample for good people here to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

You are getting confused by `[` and `[[` for indexing.

To quote from the help

> ### Recursive (list-like) objects
>
> Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the
>   specified element(s).
>
> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list.

Hence the difference

```
x <- list(a = 1:4, b= 1:2)
class(x[1])
## [1] "list"
 class(x[[1]])
## [1] "integer"
```

Without knowing what your data looks like I can't suggest a better approach to your exact problem except to say that there will be a better way.

Comment: Thanks mnel.
To clarify, what I'm looking for is a way to prevent the column entries from being lists at all. (I'm ultimately trying to export to a shapefile, and the fact that the entries are lists is generating the error "data frame contains columns of unsupported class “list”")

Comment: @user2167839 - edit your question to include a reproducible example, at the moment `for(i in nyc_districts$SUBWAY_STOP){nyc_districts$SUBWAY_STOP[i]...` is not doing what you think it is. perhaps you want `for( i in seq_along( nyc_districts$SUBWAY_STOP)){...`